Fitting a parabola through two points in which the derivatives are known with the aim of finding a minimum.
For a project I am designing an accelerated gradient descent algorithm that uses the first derivative of two points of the unknown function (as opposed to just using a single point with its derivative).
Under certain circumstances the algorithm fits a "best parabola" through two samples (where one sample at value $w$ exists of both, the function value $L(w)$ as well as the derivative $L'(w)$), and to subsequently advance to the vertex of that parabola.
Since the idea here is that we try to find a (local) minimum, it is obvious that if one of the two points has a derivative equal to zero, then that is where we should "go next" (between quotes, because in that case we're already done of course).
Or in other words, the smaller the value of the derivative, to more weight should be given to it.
Question
What is the best parabola fit through two known points, with known tangents, such that the derivative of a point closer to the vertex gets more weight? That is, if one point has a slope of zero then the resulting parabola must have its vertex there. And if both points have the same slope (or negative the other) then both must get the same weight.

Consider the points $(w_0, L(w_0))$ and $(w_1, L(w_1))$, where $w_0 \neq w_1$.
Let $P$ be the parabola $P(w) = a + bw + cw^2$ such that $P$ passes through both points.
That is,
$$P(w_0) = a + b w_0 + c w_0^2 = L(w_0) \tag{1}$$
$$P(w_1) = a + b w_1 + c w_1^2 = L(w_1) \tag{2}$$
Parameterizing by $c$ will just work fine, so lets eliminate $a$ by subtracting these two equations, and eliminate $b$ by multiplying the first with $w_1$ and the second with $w_0$ and then subtracting:
$$L(w_0) - L(w_1) = (w_0 - w_1) b + (w_0^2 - w_1^2) c \tag{3}$$
$$w_1 L(w_0) - w_0 L(w_1) = (w_1 - w_0) a + (w_1 w_0^2 - w_0 w_1^2) c \tag{4}$$
This allows to solve $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$:
$$a = \frac{w_1 L(w_0) - w_0 L(w_1)}{w_1 - w_0} + w_0 w_1 c \tag{5}$$
$$b = \frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - (w_0 + w_1) c \tag{6}$$
Filling it back in into $P$ gives
$$P(w) = \left(\frac{w_1 L(w_0) - w_0 L(w_1)}{w_1 - w_0} + w_0 w_1 c \right) + \left(\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - (w_0 + w_1) c \right) w + c w^2 \tag{7}$$
Hence the derivative of $P$ that goes through both points is
$$P'(w) = \left(\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - (w_0 + w_1) c \right) + 2c w \tag{8}$$
More specifically,
$$P'(w_0) = \frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} + (w_0 - w_1) c \tag{9-I}$$
$$P'(w_1) = \frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - (w_0 - w_1) c \tag{9-II}$$
Most likely only one these can be set equal to respectively $L'(w_0)$ or $L'(w_1)$.
For example, if we set the first one equal to $L'(w_0)$ we get the solution,
$$c = \frac{L'(w_0) - \frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1}}{w_0 - w_1} \tag{10-I}$$
while if we set the second one equal to $L'(w_1)$ we get the solution,
$$c = \frac{\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - L'(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} \tag{10-II}$$
Lets write $A = c (w_0 - w_1)$ and $B = \frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1}$ to rewrite (10-I) and (10-II) as
$$A = L'(w_0) - B \tag{11-I}$$
$$A = B - L'(w_1) \tag{11-II}$$
Define $t = \frac{L'(w_0) + L'(w_1)}{L'(w_0) - L'(w_1)}$ such that $t$ runs from $-1$ for $L'(w_0) = 0$, in which case we want case I to hold, to $0$ for $L'(w_0) = -L'(w_1)$ to $1$ for $L'(w_1) = 0$, in which case we want case II to hold.
Therefore a strong candidate for the parameterization of $A$ is
$$A = \frac{1 - t}{2}(L'(w_0) - B) + \frac{1 + t}{2}(B - L'(w_1)) \tag{12}$$
This gives us $P'(w_0) = 0$ if $L'(w_0) = 0$, $P'(w_1) = 0$ if $L'(w_1) = 0$ and sets $c$ in between when $w_0$ and $w_1$ are at equal distances left and right of the vertex. Lastly, if $w_0$ and $w_1$ are close together, and the derivatives are almost equal then both can and will be matched.
Substituting $t$ back into (12) gives
$$A = \frac{B(L'(w_1) + L'(w_0)) - 2L'(w_1)L'(w_0)}{L'(w_0) - L'(w_1)} \tag{13}$$
And thus we now also have an expression for $c$:
$$c = \frac{\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1}(L'(w_1) + L'(w_0)) - 2L'(w_1)L'(w_0)}{(w_0 - w_1)(L'(w_0) - L'(w_1))} \tag{14}$$
Edit
It turns out that the above leads to relative errors in the derivative in both points that have the same magnitude, but are of opposite sign:
$$\frac{P'(w_0) - L'(w_0)}{L'(w_0)} = -\frac{P'(w_1) - L'(w_1)}{L'(w_1)} \tag{15}$$
However, this is only the best solution if $L'(w_0)$ and $L'(w_1)$ have different sign. If the derivatives have the same sign, then it is better to let the relative errors have the same sign too, which leads to the equation
$$\frac{P'(w_0)}{L'(w_0)} = \frac{P'(w_1)}{L'(w_1)} \tag{16}$$
Combining this with (9) gives
$$\frac{\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} + (w_0 - w_1) c}{L'(w_0)} =
\frac{\frac{L(w_0) - L(w_1)}{w_0 - w_1} - (w_0 - w_1) c}{L'(w_1)}$$
from which we can solve $c$ again:
$$c = \frac{(L(w_0) - L(w_1)) (L'(w_0) - L'(w_1))}{(w_0 - w_1)^2 (L'(w_0) + L'(w_1))}, \quad \text{if } L'(w_0)L'(w_1) \geq 0 \tag{17}$$
whereas (14) becomes
$$c = \frac{(L(w_0) - L(w_1)) (L'(w_0) + L'(w_1)) - 2(w_0 - w_1)L'(w_0)L'(w_1)}{(w_0 - w_1)^2 (L'(w_0) - L'(w_1))}, \quad \text{if } L'(w_0)L'(w_1) \leq 0 \tag{18}$$
